# CoreMIDI: midiReadProc only receives the first packet of 3 packets with the same timestamp

Tags: macos, coremidi

I am working on a small program to monitor midi output from NI Maschine 2. (Idea is to add program change messages to some Parts in NI Machine and use them to trigger VJ-efects and some other stuff)

The following test case gives the problem. the test Part in NI Machine has one note and two program change messages on the first beat and a second note a 16th later.

When i hit start and capture the output with a MIDI Monitor tool i see:
[image: results from MIDI Monitor]

This is correct. Exactly what Maschine is sending.
- notice the two Control Changes and the next Note On packets have the same timestamp.

When i do the same with my simple virtual client (see code below) i get this:
[image: Results from my Virtual Client]

- as you can see the second Control Change and the Note On packets are missing!

notice also the second an third line (Song Position and Continue) also have the same timestamp and are in both cases received.

If you took the trouble to read until this point you will understand the problem.
I know the big difference between my simpel virtual client and the MIDI Monitor program is the use of a CoreMidi Service plugin for 'spying' the midi output.
Is this just a limitation of CoreMidi or am i missing something?

Below the code for the virtual client:
It is stripped down to the basic needs to receive something from NI Mashine.
The init sets up the virtual client, destination and sets the UniqueID.
The readproc is producing the NSLOG messages with the missing packets as shown above.

Any suggestions are very appreciated

```
//
//  VirtualClient.m
//  testMidiReadProc
//
//  Created by Rob Keeris on 02/06/15.
//  Copyright (c) 2015 Connector. All rights reserved.
//

#import "VirtualClient.h"

@implementation VirtualClient


SInt32          virtualinUniqueId = 1234567893;
MIDIClientRef   client;
MIDIEndpointRef virtualIn;

NSString * midiTypeName(Byte midiType){
    switch (midiType) {
        case 0x80: return @"Note Off";
        case 0x90: return @"Note On";
        case 0xB0: return @"ControlChange";
        case 0xC0: return @"ProgramChange";
        case 0xF2: return @"SongPosition";
        case 0xF8: return @"Clock";
        case 0xFA: return @"Start";
        case 0xFB: return @"Continue";
        case 0xFC: return @"Stop";
        case 0x00: return @"InvalidType";
        default: return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Unlisted midiType 0x%02x",midiType];
    }
}

void midiReadProc (const MIDIPacketList *list, void *procRef, void *srcRef) {

    const MIDIPacket *packet = &list->packet[0];  // ?defined as const to avoid compiler warnings?
    for (int i = 0; i < list->numPackets; i++) {

        if (packet->data[0] != 0xF8){ // filter out Clock messages

            NSLog(@"%llu packet(%i of %i) %@(0x%02x) 0x%02x 0x%02x",
                  packet->timeStamp,i+1,list->numPackets,midiTypeName(packet->data[0]),packet->data[0],packet->data[1],packet->data[2]);
        }

        packet = MIDIPacketNext (packet);
    }
}

- (id)init{
    OSStatus result;

    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        // Create the client
        result = MIDIClientCreate(CFSTR("myVirtualClient"), NULL, NULL, &client);
        if (result !=0) NSLog(@"MIDIClientCreate error %i",result);
        // create the destination
        result = MIDIDestinationCreate(client, CFSTR("myVirtualDestination"), midiReadProc,(__bridge void *)(self),&virtualIn);
        if (result !=0) NSLog(@"MIDIClientCreate error %i",result);
        // set the UniqueId so i dont have to toggele the output in NI Maschine
        result = MIDIObjectSetIntegerProperty(virtualIn, kMIDIPropertyUniqueID, virtualinUniqueId);
        if (result !=0) NSLog(@"MIDIClientCreate error %i",result);

    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

**Extra info**
Put in this extra test in response to the hints of Gene to see what happens when
removing the 0xF8 filter and using a printf instead of NSLog();

Output from MIDI Monitor:
[image]

Output form my code:

[image]

No solution but now a clock is received with the same timestamp.

Tempo in this test was set to 50 BPM (so one clock every 50 ms) 
I checked to see if there are missing clock pulses but this isn't the case. All clocks are received with approx the expected timestamp.

Comment: did you find a solution? I am also having trouble with same timestamped messages

Answer (score 0):

Minor comment here.
Since you're doing this:

```
const MIDIPacket *packet = &list->packet[0];  // ?defined as const to avoid compiler warnings?
```

This

```
for (int i = 0; i < list->numPackets; i++) {
```

should be

```
for (int i = 0; i < list->numPackets; ++i) {
```

But that doesn't fix your problem.
What happens when you remove the filtering "if" (besides getting lots of F8s)?
Shot in the dark: try printf to see if NSLog is up to no good.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I added the results of your suggestion to the question. I'm afraid it doesn't bring a lot of extra clues.

Answer (score 0):

I think i found out wat the problem is.
The packets are not missing but put together in the data[0] of the first package.
Another post (proper-use-of-midipacketlistadd-coremidi) put me on the right track.

[image]

for this test i put a chord of 3 notes and 2 control change messages on the first bar and a single not on the sixteenth and a singe control change .

Well, its clear the control change holds the 2 control change's and the 3 NoteOn messages. The NoteOf message holds the 3 NoteOf's.

Is this a bug in Coremidi or bad behavieur of the programmer on the other side?

**EDIT**
This is solved.
As Kurt pointed out its just normal and you have to be prepared for multiple messages in one packet. So you have to do something like below.

Thanks for all input.

```
#import "VirtualClient.h"

@implementation VirtualClient


SInt32          virtualinUniqueId = 1234567893;
MIDIClientRef   client;
MIDIEndpointRef virtualIn;
MIDITimeStamp previousTimeStamp;

struct MIDIMessage
{
   char* description;
   int   messageLength;
};
typedef struct MIDIMessage MIDIMessage;

// incomplete list of possible messages but suffucient for this test
const MIDIMessage x00 = {"Error! or Unlisted",0};
const MIDIMessage x80 = {"Note Off",3};
const MIDIMessage x90 = {"Note On",3};
const MIDIMessage xB0 = {"ControlChange",3};
const MIDIMessage xC0 = {"ProgramChange",2};
const MIDIMessage xF2 = {"SongPosition",3};
const MIDIMessage xF8 = {"Clock",1};
const MIDIMessage xFA = {"Start",1};
const MIDIMessage xFB = {"Continue",1};
const MIDIMessage xFC = {"Stop",1};

MIDIMessage midiType(Byte midiType){

    switch (midiType) {

        case 0x80: return x80;
        case 0x90: return x90;
        case 0xB0: return xB0;
        case 0xC0: return xC0;

        case 0xF2: return xF2;
        case 0xF8: return xF8;
        case 0xFA: return xFA;
        case 0xFB: return xFB;
        case 0xFC: return xFC;

        default: return x00;
    }

}

void midiReadProc (const MIDIPacketList *list, void *procRef, void *srcRef) {

int index;
int messageLength;
const MIDIPacket *packet = &list->packet[0];

// handle packets
for (int i =0;i< list->numPackets;++i){

    // handle messages in each packet
    index = 0;
    while (index < packet->length){

        messageLength = midiType(packet->data[index]).messageLength;

        if (messageLength){

            printf("%llu packet(%i of %i) %s", packet->timeStamp,i+1,list->numPackets,midiType(packet->data[index]).description);
            for (int x =1; x< messageLength;x++)
                printf(" data[%i]:0x%02x",x,packet->data[index+x]);
            printf("\n");
            index+=messageLength;

        }
        else{

            printf("Unlisted comand! printing rest of bytes");
            for (int i =index; i < packet->length;i++)
                printf("0x%02x ",packet->data[i]);
            printf("\n");
            break;

        }

    }
    packet = MIDIPacketNext (packet);
    }
}

- (id)init{
    OSStatus result;
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        // Create the client
        result = MIDIClientCreate(CFSTR("myVirtualClient"), NULL, NULL, &client);
        if (result !=0) NSLog(@"MIDIClientCreate error %i",result);
        // create the destination
        result = MIDIDestinationCreate(client, CFSTR("myVirtualDestination"), midiReadProc,(__bridge void *)(self),&virtualIn);
        if (result !=0) NSLog(@"MIDIClientCreate error %i",result);
        // set the UniqueId so i dont have to toggele the output in NI Maschine
        result = MIDIObjectSetIntegerProperty(virtualIn, kMIDIPropertyUniqueID, virtualinUniqueId);
     if (result !=0) NSLog(@"MIDIClientCreate error %i",result);

    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

Comment: This isn't a bug in CoreMIDI, or in the sender of the MIDI data. It's perfectly normal. A MIDIPacket is allowed to contain one or more MIDI messages (or a partial sysex message). You are expected to use the length field, parse that many bytes of the data, and interpret them.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I will be more careful next time and think twice  before using the word bug.  It was because I couldn't  find an example of the proper use.  Well, won't forget this.